# Linux Root group change chmod for root owned to 770

Tags: permissions, root, group, chmod

I'd like to have normal user account assigned to root group (which I've done already) and change mod of all files that are owned by root user to 770, If I understood it well in result of that every user that is assigned to root group will obtain full access to those files and as well can be treated as root user.
My question is if I do this system can take a damage?

Comment: Nope.  Am looking for alternative way to make normal user with full privilege with no changing uid to 0.  Because I am tired using sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even assuming you meant `chmod g=u` rather than `chmod 770`, it may well break some of the PAM security modules, including those that manage logins. It will break `ssh` logins, as `ssh` checks permissions on `$HOME` and all parent directories.

If, as you suggest in your comments, you simply want to avoid using `sudo` there are some options that spring to mind:

1. Login as root
2. Run `sudo -s` at the start of your session
3. Continue using `sudo` but configure it to stop asking you for a password

Given your requirements, of all of these I would recommend only the third option.

Comment: Many thanks for help I have avoid system crash.  I will consider second  option